# Conditionally suppress record ID if it is the same as previous record ID but display the running total in detail records of crystal reports

Tags: summarize, crystal-reports-2010, drop-duplicates

I have a sales report that is grouped by Invoice_ID field. There are multiple invoices on the report. Within the Invoice_ID field, there are multiple detail records that may have the same product name but different quantity.

Invoice 12356
Product Name    Quantity
Apples          25
Bananas         100
Bananas         200
Bananas         11
Cherries        50

If the product name is the same, then I only want to see the product name once and display a running total for that product in the quantity field.

**Desired output**
Product Name    Quantity
Apples            25
Bananas           311
Cherries          50

I've tried suppress if product name is same as the previous name but then I do not see the running total only the amount for the first bananas field (100).  And it seems I cannot drag a running total into a detail record

If I suppress the product name if duplicate I get:
Invoice 12356
Product Name    Quantity
Apples          25
Bananas         100
200
11
Cherries        50

but I want to see:
**Desired output**
Product Name    Quantity
Apples            25
Bananas           311
Cherries          50

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).